# how do I change the F3 and F4 to copy and paste?

Tags: keyboard

Using the Magic Keyboard, how do I change the F3 and F4 back to copy and paste?  The Apple Magic Keyboard with High Sierra launches mission control or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Open System Preferences->Keyboard. Disable F3 first:

[image]

Then add an application keyboard shortcut:

[image]

Make sure that the text matches the menu item exactly ("Copy" in your case).

PS: Repeat for Paste/F4

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work.   It won't let me type anything in the box (manually an "f" and a "3" for copy or the key itself.

Comment: @Nancy Did you try to just press the function key itself (maybe Fn-Function Key, depending on your settings)?